# Windows open file dialog, quick way to home directory?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

I would like to navigate the Windows open file dialog entirely with the keyboard. Is there any quick way to access my home directory (c:\Users\Me)? Something like an equivalent to ~ in linux?

I use both Windows 7 and Windows XP, so input for either or both would be welcome.

Comment: somewhat useful but maybe something better will come along: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/stupid-geek-tricks-navigate-in-the-file-opensave-dialog-with-the-keyboard/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file dialog accepts environment variables, so you could set a custom variable like `%H%` to the needed path.

I don't know where Windows 7 puts the envvar edit interface (in WinXP it used to be at *`sysdm.cpl` → Advanced → Advanced → Environment*), but if you find it, add the following variable:

- Name: `H`
- Value: `%UserProfile%`

Comment: Thanks. I had tried this before but couldn't get it to work. The issue was that I had to restart the program (Notepad++) before it would reload its environment variables.

Comment: It's accessible from Control Panel, but I never bother trying to remember how to get there that way. Just start typing "environment variable" in the Start Menu search box and you'll see two options - one for editing envars for the current user account, and the other for editing system envars.

Comment: Windows tries really hard to hide user directory. It's just super annoying having to manually surf to that directory.

Comment: On the other hand, Windows now has a Start Menu button _and_ a dedicated desktop icon for precisely this directory.

Answer (score 0):

It is already present in newer version of Windows (screenshot is from Windows 8.1). But not always. If anyone figures out when does it appear and when not and how to control it, I'm all ears.

"stein" is my username and that is my home folder there in the left side.

[image: File dialog showing home directory]